# Spring using wrong application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a ***SpringBoot*** application with a set of ***application.yaml*** files for different profiles.

```
application.yaml
application-dev.yaml
application-test.yaml
```

Those files are in classpath and there is no extra configuration to switch them, other then just changing profile in configuration "Active profiles" section of intellij.

One of my spring beans is  property dependent

it have a constructor that looks like this

```
@Service
public class MyBean {
   private static appUrl;

   public MyBean(@Value("${application.app-url}") String appUrl){
      MyBean.appUrl = Objects.requireNotNull(appUrl);
   }
}
```

The whole point of this is to **fail** bean construction (thus causing application failing to start) if appUrl is absent in properties file.

In both ***application.yaml*** and ***application-dev.yaml*** property looks like this

```
application:
   app-url: http://someurl
```

I expected that if i remove app-url from ***application-dev.yaml*** and then start application with dev profile it suppose to fail. However i discovered that when property for that profile is missing the property from ***application.yaml*** is taken instead of it.

Two questions:

1. How can i prevent this 'take value from default application.yaml if missing' behavior
2. Is there a better way to make MANDATORY properties to ensure application fail on startup if missing properties

Comment: Di you add add -Dspring.profiles.active=dev (or your profile name) in VM option?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property on `application.properties` as

```
local.so68824465.prop1=value1
```

could be set to `null` on `application-dev.properties` as

```
local.so68824465.prop1=#{null}
```

Test class

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Value("${local.so68824465.prop1:zzzzzzz}")
    String prop1;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("local.so68824465.prop1:" + (prop1 == null ? "is null" : prop1));
    }
}
```

**Case #1 `local.so68824465.prop1=dev-value` on `application-dev.properties`**

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev ./gradlew bootRun
```

> local.so68824465.prop1:dev-value

**Case #2 `local.so68824465.prop1=#{null}` on `application-dev.properties`**

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev ./gradlew bootRun
```

> local.so68824465.prop1:is null

**Case #3 No specific active profile**

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

> local.so68824465.prop1:value1

**Case #4 No specific active profile and missing property on both files**

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

> local.so68824465.prop1:zzzzzzz

Tested on:

> id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken that is not possible. Spring will always fall back to `application.yml` if it exists. Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config for more details on this.

The only way to achieve 1 and 2 is to simply delete `application.yml`.